# ¿Cómo le paso la fecha al "New Date" en otro formato?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo declarado el inicio de la fecha de la siguiente manera:

```
new Date(2020, 0, 5, 12, 0)  //año, mes, día, hora, minuto.
```

Pero yo utilizo los formatos de las fechas de la siguiente manera:

```
05-01-2020 12:00
DD-MM-Y hh:mm
```

¿Cómo le indico que lo lea tal cual se lo mando en ese orden?, desconozco el método.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes obtener la fecha por partes, extrayendo el dia, mes, año, minutos, etc.

```js
var fecha = new Date(2020, 1, 5, 12, 0);
//5-1-2020 12:0
//DD-MM-Y hh:mm
function formatDate(date) {
  return date.getDate() + '-' + date.getMonth() + '-' + date.getFullYear() + ' ' + date.getHours() + ':' + date.getMinutes();
}

console.log(formatDate(fecha));  // show current date-time in console
```